# Neutron-Antineutron Annihilation

Tags: nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, neutrons, pions

Is the process  $n + \bar{n} \rightarrow \pi^{+} + \pi^{-} + \pi^{0}$ possible?

Comment: how you can explain that energy is not conserved for this process?

Comment: @ Heitor, As it is your opinion that the energy conservation is violated, please show the justification in the support of your claim.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within a few MeV, from isospin symmetry of the strong interaction,  it is similar to the antiproton proton annihilation which happens even at rest: Role of Delta exchange for proton-antiproton annihilation into [two-pion and three-pion channels](http://cds.cern.ch/record/544655?ln=en) .

No problem of energy conservation due to the much smaller masses of the pions to the two nucleons.

[image: antiproton proton annihilation]

> [This is an actual bubble](http://particleadventure.org/all_decay.html) chamber photograph of an antiproton (entering from the bottom of the picture), colliding with a proton (at rest), and annihilating. Eight pions were produced in this annihilation. One decayed into a mu + and a neutrino. The paths of positive and negative pions curve opposite ways in the magnetic field, and the neutral  leaves no track.

This is antiproton proton, but antineutron-neutron would look the same (impossible  to get a beam of antineutrons). Average pion multiplicity at rest is [five,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ex/9708025.pdf) two pi0 3 charged  (note, average).

Comment: Anna I think throwing neutrons on high or relativistic speed together has nothing to do with an annihilation where particles of different electric sign and somehow equal structure (electron - positron or proton - antiproton) self-approach each other.

Comment: I recall that the *predominant* baryon-antibaryon annihilation channel is five pions, but don't have a reference handy.

Comment: getting an answer from anna deserves a positive score.

Comment: @rob Do you know if this is something that can be found in the [PDB](http://pdg.lbl.gov/)?

Comment: @SeanLake The PDG data on particle-antiparticle annihilations is restricted to meson states (that is, $q\bar q$).

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Note, "happens even at rest".  see http://particleadventure.org/all_decay.html . The incoming antiproton has very small momentum and it loses a lot of it from ionization on the hydrogen molecules of the bubble chamber.  Annihilation means loss of identifying quantum numbers. There are no protons or antiprotons in the product. neutron antineutron is the same, more difficult experiment.

Comment: @SeanLake  the average multiplicity at rest  of antiproton proton annihilation is into five pions, 3 charged two neutral.   https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ex/9708025.pdf  ,page 3.   Unfortunately fig  41.5  http://pdg.lbl.gov/2010/reviews/rpp2010-rev-cross-section-plots.pdf  of the particle data book has a complicated function for the multiplicities of antiprotons ( subtractin the proton one) one needs to go to a library for the originals which were in the 1970s)

Comment: Anna, this more difficult experiment was carried out? What I'm curious also is, the produced antineutrons - and they are produced according to this forum - have annihilated when they reached an obstacle from the experimental environment?

Comment: Have a look at this http://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm an antineutron annihilation in the bubble chamber .  if you have access to a library see this http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.184.1413

Answer (score 3):

It might be suppressed for reasons I am too lazy to examine the process for (symmetry concerns, especially related to rotations), but energy is not a problem. If the two neutrinos have enough kinetic energy, it can be converted into the mass of the pions (among other possibilities, including electron-positron production). In math we're looking for solutions that satisfy all of the following equations:
$$\begin{align}E_{\nu} + E_{\overline{\nu}} &= E_{+} + E_{0} + E_{-}, \\
\vec{p}_{\nu} + \vec{p}_{\overline{\nu}} &= \vec{p}_{+} + \vec{p}_{0} + \vec{p}_{-}, \\
m_{\nu}^2 c^4 &= E_{\nu}^2 - c^2 \vec{p}_{\nu}\cdot \vec{p}_{\nu}, \\
m_{\overline{\nu}}^2 c^4 &= E_{\overline{\nu}}^2 - c^2 \vec{p}_{\overline{\nu}}\cdot \vec{p}_{\overline{\nu}}, \\
m_+^2c^4 & = E_{+}^2 - c^2 \vec{p}_{+}\cdot \vec{p}_{+}, \\
m_0^2c^4 & = E_{0}^2 - c^2 \vec{p}_{0}\cdot \vec{p}_{0}, \ \mathrm{and} \\
m_-^2c^4 & = E_{-}^2 - c^2 \vec{p}_{-}\cdot \vec{p}_{-}. \end{align}$$
That's 9 equations and 12 unknowns, so the space of possible solutions has 3 dimensions.

Comment: sorry but the question is about neutrons.

Comment: No difference in the math - just substitute $\nu\rightarrow n$ and you'll get the exact same set of equations.

Answer (score -1):

Nice question. As anna pointed out if neutron and anti-neutron are throwing together with some MeV, no question they will splash into different particles and EM radiation.

But what means annihilation? Usually it means the attraction of charged particles from different sign, for example an electron and a positron. **During the approach** they emit EM radiation and this process - like it happens between electron and proton or between positron and anti-proton - doesn't stops at some distance.

The neutron and the anti-neutron will not approach by themself and due to noexisting electric fields no annihilation takes place. [There](https://www.academia.edu/19657550/Complex_one-dimensional_structures_of_space) is an elaboration of mine about how the approach of charged particles can be modelled and due to this a neutron - antineutron annihilation is impossible (from the above definition of what an annihilation is). The existence of electric fields allows particles to get bonded or to be repealed.

Comment: *"Usually it means the attraction of charged particles from different sign"* No. It doesn't. Sure, most of the usual example involve charged particles but that fact has absolutely nothing to do with the notion of annihilation which does involve the destruction of a pair of states having opposite counted quantum numbers (lepton, baryon, weak-hyperchage, electric charge and so on). Neutrons may have electric charge zero, but they carry baryon number.

Comment: Your prediction that neutron-antineutron annihilation cannot occur is wrong. The relevant literature is easy to find.

Comment: @rob Any source for experimental data on no relativistic velocity?

Comment: @dmckee Please give sources for change of particle interactions from not fast moving (MeV) particles and pure energy at the next moment.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I'll turn your challenge around: you survey the literature and figure out what the energies involved are and where the data are missing.  I don't know to what extent antineutrons thermalize before annihilating, so you can't just consider beam energy.

Comment: Positronium annihilation happens at $\mathrm{eV}$ relative energies and on average at relative rest; the formation of the 'atomic' state is accompanied by radiating off the relative kinetic energy. Nor does "pure energy" mean anything; many annihilation ends in photon states, but those are only characterized as "pure energy" in pop-sci and science fiction.

Comment: @dmckee To conclude from charged particles with their opposite electric fields to neutrons is a strange thought. What in the experiments with antineutrons happens when the hit an obstacle or came in contact with gas molecules? Are they annihilate with the nucleuses neutrons? Any experimental evidence?